# What's wrong PHP field check function

Tags: php, forms, function, field

I have that function but it's not working.

```
function Checkfields($fields){
    $ret = false;
    foreach($fields as $field) {
        if ($_POST[$field] == "" || !isset($_POST[$field])) {
            $ret = true;
        }
    }
    if ($ret) {
        $ret = "All fields are required.";
        header('Location: ?erro='. $erro);
    }
}
```

and i use like that:

```
Checkfields(array("username","password"));
```

**UPDATED:**
I already tried to change to:

```
function Checkfields($fields){
    $ret = false;
    foreach($fields as $field) {
        if ($_POST[$field] == "" || !isset($_POST[$field])) {
            $ret = true;
        }
    }
    if ($ret) {
        $erro = "All fields are required.";
        header('Location: ?erro='. $erro);
    }
}
```

and nothing happens.

Comment: please give some more details then "not working"

Comment: You have `$ret = "All fields are required.";`. Shouldn't it be `$erro = "All fields are required.";`?

Comment: just return nothing, i put the POST empty and no redirection.

Comment: What's appears for you?

Comment: _"not working"_ is like going to the doctor and stating _"I'm sick"_.

Comment: i already changed $ret variable to $erro and nothing again

Answer (score 0):

```
function Checkfields($fields){
        $ret = false;
        foreach($fields as $field) {
            if (!isset($_POST[$field])) {
                $ret = true;
            }
        }
        if ($ret) {
            $error = "All fields are required.";
            header('Location: ?erro='. $error);
        }
}
```

Exist two bugs in your code validation in variable POST.. if element don't exist appears error

And when $ret == true

header you put

```
$ret = "All fields are required.";
        header('Location: ?erro='. $erro);
```

When redirect to other page don't send response error

Answer (score 0):

Why your code is not redirecting , is probably because of the header function call

you may have to call like

```
header("Location:http://www.example.com/page.php?erro=$err")
```

replace example.com/page.php to the page you want it to redirect to. As the location basically  creates a 302 redirection and the browser will get redirected to the new url. So you should supply absolute path.